# No data is sent by Google Tag - GA4 how to troubleshoot the installation

Tags: google-analytics-4

I try to set up GA4 in a test website. I followed the instructions that are available on google.
I did tag manual installation, copied-in google tag script in site index.php file between HEAD tags, it looks like this:

```
<head>
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-884KS4TXD2"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-884KS4TXD2');
</script>

...

</head>
```

and... nothing is shown on Google Analytics page - there is no data on real time report as well.

How can I check whether data is really sent when user opens index.php file?
I run netstat -a on client pc - there are lots of entries there... should I look for any GA4 specific connection?

I tried opening my website from inside and outside of local network... no positive result - data is still not available at GA4 page.

How can I start troubleshooting this instillation?

Comment: I think you forgot your google tag script and also `gtm.js`. [Example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/index.html#L53-L79)

Comment: OK. You think I should install Google Tag Manager as well? I thought that manual gtag installation is used when I do not want to install gtm... OK.. I will check this once again with the manual/tutorials. Thanks.

Comment: well... according to the documentation this should work without GTM, but I will install it as it is recommended way of implementation...

Comment: OK... I have finally figured this out. The problem was... uBlocker that was installed in my browser (commercials blocker). It blocked google analytics and Tag Manager as well. Now I have GTM installed and working. THANKS for pointing me in right direction.